# Appcelerator. Update table with JSON data without refresh

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

I am developing an iOS app using Appcelerator. I got a table on one window which contains six sections. Every section contains one or more items (rows).

When a user clicks a row she is forwarded to another window where she can edit the item. I then would like to update that row in the table without reloading the table completely.

The JSON object for the row is sent to the edit page where it is updated with the latest details and then sent back to the first window where it updates the old object.

The problem I am facing now is how to "refresh" the table. I am using sections.

This is the code for the first window: http://pastie.org/2189569

This is the code for the second window: http://pastie.org/2189592

Do anyone know of a better way or a way to solve this problem?

Thankful for all input!